# run action cause exception - (cocos2d-iphone)

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

When i put

```
[_nextProjectile runAction:[CCSequence actions:
                            [CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:rotateDuration angle:cocosAngle],
                            [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:nil selector:nil],
                            nil]];
```

xcode throws an exception in execute method

## pragma mark CCCallFuncN

```
@implementation CCCallFuncN

-(void) execute
{
    [targetCallback_ performSelector:selector_ withObject:target_];
}
```

@end

Without runAction it works fine..
can any one help !! ?

Answer (score 1):

Remove below line:

```
[CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:nil selector:nil],
```

Or do something like this:

```
[_nextProjectile runAction:[CCSequence actions:
                            [CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:rotateDuration angle:cocosAngle],
                            [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(execute)],
                            nil]];


-(void) execute
{

}
```

Comment: yup, this callfunc is nonsensical, trying to call an unknown selector on a non-existing object

Comment: Removing 
[CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:nil selector:nil],
Solves the problem  

But,i can not put [_nextProjectile runAction:[CCSequence actions:
                            [CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:rotateDuration angle:cocosAngle],
                            [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(execute)],
                            nil]];


-(void) execute
{

}

because execute method is not user defined method.

Comment: hmmm...change execute to VDExecute :P

Comment: @ Guru kuch bhi haan !! :P